# Greenshot import screens into Powepoint - how to make it import into modified slide layout?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, greenshot

I seek help, ralated to the Powerpoint slide layout when pasting screenshots from Greenshot. (no setting available in preferences of greenshot as far as I could find)

I need to change parameters of slide layout, which is created automatically throught process of importing from greenshot to powerpoint. Powerpoint is supposed to use LayoutPictureWithCaption I suppose (I did not find any help so I was searching through code in GitHub, although I am not programmer or coder, this wild guessing)

The code in https://gist.github.com/ndxbn/817a7ac206f53c26dc23a008853b6436 states

; For Powerpoint: Slide layout, changing this to a wrong value will fallback on ppLayoutBlank!!
PowerpointSlideLayout=ppLayoutPictureWithCaption

Consequently, if I try to modify Layout of the slide to which is incoming screenshot pasted,

-> I try to modify LayoutPictureWithCaption in SlideMaster view in the PowerPoint.

However this seem not to work. Everytime I change it to layout I wish, save and try Greenshot, it still gets in the original format of the layout ... moreover afterlooking in the SlideMaster - newly created layout is present .. with name along the line:

-> 1_LayoutPictureWithCaption
... identical to the original layout (the one I tried to modify .. the LayoutPictureWithCaption layout is still present and modified according my will, it just happen, that new layout is introduced with similar name, which is ruling the import now ... deleting it or modifying it does not help)

Actually if I click on "new slide" it creates the slide according my modifications in SlideMaster, it is only the process of importing through Greenshot, which starts to repeat the original layout.

Is the layout for LayoutPictureWithCaption somehow imported or influenced from Greenshot?

How to proceed to successfully modify the layout of the slide with screenshots from Greenshot?

(basically too much space is wasted for caption and text ... and for any fast work it is very time consuming to change parameters of every screenshot taken to enlarge it and positioning it manually)

Workflow of using Greenshot to Powerpoint is amazing in theory, but the screenshots are too tiny. }they fit into prearanged window for picture / which is also convenient ... but this is only small portion of the slide ... I just changed the parameters of the layout so, that the picture ie screenshot would be more dominant and more central to the slide ... however I cannot make the Greenshot make to import through it)

Comment: ; Greenshot Office configuration
[Office]
...
...
; For Outlook: Allow export in meeting items
OutlookAllowExportInMeetings=False
; For Word: Lock the aspect ratio of the image
WordLockAspectRatio=True
; For Powerpoint: Lock the aspect ratio of the image
PowerpointLockAspectRatio=True
; For Powerpoint: Slide layout, changing this to a wrong value will fallback on ppLayoutBlank!!
PowerpointSlideLayout=ppLayoutPictureWithCaption

Comment: Your post is too long with too much detail. Could you please just say what you are doing and what goes wrong?

Comment: Greenshot takes screenshots. I take as a destination for them PowerPoint.

And I cannot modify the way how the screenshot imported from Greenshot is posted on the slide in Power Point.I ask how to do that.

PowerPoint has layouts for slides, and one of those layouts is managing the way screenshot is imported on the slide. I tried to change it there.

If I go into power Point and change the particular layout for the slide, it is not helpful, because for some reason, my change is overruled in the moment of the next import from Greenshot.

Greenshot itself somehow governs the layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to right-click About Greenshot. When the about screen loads, hit "I" on your keyboard. The Greenshot.ini file will open. Use THIS VERSION of the file, not the one you can navigate to through File Explorer. Keep this file open and Exit Greenshot. Once Greenshot is closed, scroll down on the Greenshot.ini file to the Powerpoint section. Comment out the "PowerpointSlideLayout=ppLayoutPictureWithCaption" line by adding a semi colon in front. Below this line, add PowerpointSlideLayout=ppLayoutBlank
Save the file and close it. Reopen Greenshot and take a new screenshot, sending it to PowerPoint. Hopefully this will work for you. I successfully made the change this morning after searching endlessly for an answer yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out all keywords for the powerpoint layouts from this page

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppslidelayout

Exit Greenshot then in greenshot.ini file (it is located in appdata/roaming/greenshot directory)
change this PowerpointSlideLayout config to the layout you see in the above webpage.
with semicolon comment out the original config and add the new one under that line as below.

> ;PowerpointSlideLayout=ppLayoutPictureWithCaption
>
> PowerpointSlideLayout=ppLayoutTextAndObject

I have chosen ppLayoutTextAndObject and title and screenshot fitted better

[image]